# string split using regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, split

My string is `"30OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK30OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK120"` 
i want to split it in digits and 'OK' string, my expected output is

```
array(0=>30,1=>OK,2=>OK,......,n=>120)
```

currently i am using this

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

but it only returns me digits i.e. 30,30,120 
please help me to get above expected output

Comment: `explode` on OK

Comment: @rtfm `OK` needs to be in the result. Using `explode` with `OK` as the delimiter means `OK` won't be in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from least efficient down to most efficient patterns, given your input sample:

- `/\d+|OK/`         (96 steps)    <-- Shammel's pattern
- `/OK|\d+/`         (77 steps)    #faster alternative first
- `/\d+|[^\d]{2}`    (74 steps)    #make OK delimiter non-literal
- `/[^\d]{2}|\d+/`   (55 steps)    #faster alternative first

I'd say use the 55 steps one.

```
$in = '30OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK30OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK120';
var_export(preg_match_all('/[^\d]{2}|\d+/', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
```

Note, `preg_match_all()` creates a multi-dim array.

Another option is to use `preg_split()`.  By using a couple of flags in its fourth parameter, the same result can be achieve with an amazingly brief pattern with minimal efficiency loss compared to my best pattern above.

```
var_export(preg_split('/(OK)/', $in, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
// or /([^\d]{2})/
```

This method returns a 1-dim array (not a true/false with a variable to reference) with a four-character pattern in 110 steps (or 104 with non-literal OK delimiting) .  So for this case `preg_match_all()` is twice as fast.

Comment: How you are calculating steps?...sorry i am very bad at regex

Comment: @LeenaVashistha regex101 does this calculation for you:  https://regex101.com/r/9Xp8EV/1  (everyone is "bad" at regex in the beginning, do not dismay)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is…

```
preg_match_all('(\d+|OK)', $string, $matches);
```

- `\d+` - One or more digits
- `|` - or
- `OK` - Capital `O` followed by capital `K`